# Different checkbox selected on click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need little help with this:

```
HTML
<div id="toggle">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><input type="checkbox" id="test" value="2014" name="test" checked/> 2014</li>
    <div style="display:block;" id="clear-checked">
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="test" value="2013"  name="test" /> 2013</li>
    <div id="clear-checked">
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a><br />
        <a href="#">January</a>
    </div>

</ul>
```

Clear

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("slow");

         if( $('li').hasClass('active') ) {
             $("#test:checkbox").prop('checked', true);

         } 
         else {

            $("#test:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });

 $('#check-all').click(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
});
$('#uncheck-all').click(function(){
$("#test:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
$('#clear-checked').attr("style","display:none;");
$("li").removeClass("active");
});
```

});

When I select secont div automatcly need to check checkbox, but that one is in inside div, not the upper one. Also on clear link, 2 div is not recognized so check box and div dont get block:none. Need little help, I will appriciated alot! Thanks

Live demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/HsYrD/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Changed your `id="mycheckboxdiv"` and `id="mycheckbox"` to classes instead.  I usually only use `ID's` for unique elements I know in some cases duplicate `ID`'s can cause issues.

By taking advantage of `this` which keeps track of which element was changed you can apply the changes to the correct `mycheckboxdiv`, and it can be done with one function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mycheckbox').change(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.mycheckboxdiv').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).parent().find('.disabled').removeClass().addClass('enabled');
    });
});
```

Example

http://fiddle.jshell.net/krF28/1/

Comment: its okay for the class, but how can I make to add/remove/open/close upon checkbox? thanks for the response.

Comment: @user2409020 Sorry not quite sure I understand, did you check the `fiddle example`? Do you want the class to go back to `disabled` when the check box is unchecked after being checked?

Comment: @user2409020 please mark an answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the respond, I put answer below of what I need. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to this kind of thing, but my initial guess would be that you need distinct IDs on the two different checkboxes

Comment: That would work if he gave distinct ID's for the check boxes and div's and then made two change functions one for each check box and then targeted the appropriate `.disabled` elements from there.  However it can be in much less code using classes.

Comment: that isnt right solution atm, because will be PHP for that part, all "box" need to be same html :S

Answer (score 1):

This was what I need it, one friend helped me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('input[type=checkbox]:not("li")').click(function(e) {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    } else {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });

                $("li:not('input[type=checkbox]')").click(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass("active");
                    $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("slow");
                    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
                    } else {
                        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#check-all').click(function(){
                    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
                });

                $('#uncheck-all').click(function(){
                    $('.clear-checked').attr("style", "display:none;");
                    $('li').each(function(i, obj) {
                        $(obj).removeClass("active");
                        $(obj).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
                    });

                });
            });
```

Thanks to all that respond.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working for you.  My fiddle was wrong the whole time I guess I accidentally forgot to update it.  It was supposed to be http://fiddle.jshell.net/krF28/4/